# jupyter notebook keeps reconnecting

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting error while connecting the jupyter notebook. It says connecting to the kernel. I'm not able to execute any of the queries in that. Could anyone help me out with this.

Below is the error message and logs in anaconda prompt.

```
LOGS ::

[I 16:48:48.414 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 0eb0478c-3ad8-4c50-af16-31e66bf45358
[I 16:48:48.414 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 0eb0478c-3ad8-4c50-af16-31e66bf45358:025E6CA0A7AB437F9F3FFF4C9F7A728C
[I 16:48:49.269 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f
[I 16:48:49.270 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[W 16:48:49.286 NotebookApp] zmq message arrived on closed channel
[W 16:48:49.286 NotebookApp] zmq message arrived on closed channel
[I 16:48:49.286 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:51.263 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f
[I 16:48:51.263 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:51.278 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:53.269 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f
[I 16:48:53.269 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:53.282 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:55.257 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f
[I 16:48:55.259 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
[I 16:48:55.275 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for a9b2c0c5-63ab-4f60-b49f-12279703c32f:974506A3ADF64A18A1C002CF49107209
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jupyter behind a nginx proxy, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350182/jupyter-notebook-keeps-reconnecting-to-kernel) may be effective.

Add this line to nginx conf.

**proxy_http_version 1.1;**